# Regex match semicolon but not in comments or quotes

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I want to use a regex test to return all the matched semicolons, but only if they're outside of quotes (nested quotes), and not commented code.

```
testfunc();
testfunc2("test;test");
testfunc3("test';test");
testfunc4('test";test');
//testfunc5();
/* testfunc6(); */
/*
  testfunc7();
*/
/*
  //testfunc8();
*/
testfunc9("test\"test");
```

Only the semicolons on the end of each example should be returned by the regex string.

I've been playing around with the below, but it fails on example testfunc3 and testfun9. It also doesn't ignore comments...

```
/;(?=(?:(?:[^"']*+["']){2})*+[^"']*+\z)/g
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you're using the wrong tool for the job. This isn't a job for a regular expression. Consider `/* testfunc("la la la */");` for example. You'll need to write code rather than an expression.

Comment: You need a parser. RegEx, is not good at "matching" pairs.

Comment: why use a parser, when the problem is in the regular languages ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have time to convert this into JS. Here is the regex in a Perl sample, the regex will work with JS though.

C comments, double/single string quotes - taken from "strip C comments" by Jeffrey Friedl and later modified by Fred Curtis, adapted to include C++ comments and the target semi-colon (by me).

Capture group 1 (optional), includes all up to semi-colon, group 2 is semi-colon (but can be anything).

Modifiers are //xsg.

The regex below is used in the substitution operator s/pattern/replace/xsg (ie: replace with $1[$2] ).

I think your post is just to find out if this can be done. I can include a commented regex if you really need it.

```
$str = <<EOS;
testfunc();
testfunc2("test;test"); 
testfunc3("test';test");
testfunc4('test";test');
//testfunc5();
/* testfunc6(); */
/*
  testfunc7();
*/
/*
  //testfunc8();
*/
testfunc9("test\"test");
EOS

$str =~ s{
     ((?:(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|.[^/"'\\;]*))*?)(;)
 }
 {$1\[$2\]}xsg;

print $str;
```

Output

```
testfunc()[;]
testfunc2("test;test")[;]
testfunc3("test';test")[;]
testfunc4('test";test')[;]
//testfunc5();
/* testfunc6(); */
/*
  testfunc7();
*/
/*
  //testfunc8();
*/
testfunc9("test"test")[;]
```

Expanded with comments

```
 (  ## Optional non-greedy, Capture group 1
   (?:
      ## Comments
        (?:
            /\*         ##  Start of /* ... */ comment
            [^*]*\*+    ##  Non-* followed by 1-or-more *'s
            (?:
                [^/*][^*]*\*+
            )*          ##  0-or-more things which don't start with /
                        ##    but do end with '*'
            /           ##  End of /* ... */ comment
          |  
            //          ## Start of // ... comment
            (?:
                [^\\]         ## Any Non-Continuation character ^\
              |               ##   OR
                \\\n?         ## Any Continuation character followed by 0-1 newline \n

             )*?            ## To be done 0-many times, stopping at the first end of comment

             \n         ##  End of // comment
        )

     | ##  OR,  various things which aren't comments, group 2:
        (?:
            " (?: \\. | [^"\\] )* "  ## Double quoted text
          |
            ' (?: \\. | [^'\\] )* '  ## Single quoted text
          |
            .           ##  Any other char
            [^/"'\\;]*  ##  Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape
        )               ##  or continuation (escape + newline) AND are NOT semi-colon ;
   )*?
 )
  ## Capture grou 2, the semi-colon
 (;)
```

Comment: Living up to Perl's reputation as executable line noise. :)

Answer (score 1):

This would work for all your examples, but it depends how close the code you want to apply it to is to the example:

```
;(?!\S|(?:[^;]*\*/))
```

`;` - match the semicolon

`(?!` - negative lookahead - ensure that ->

`\S` - there is no non-whitespace character after the semicolon

`|(?:[^;]*\*/))` - and if there is a whitespace char, ensure that up to the next `;` there is no `*/` sign

Let me know if you get any problems with that.

If that's something that you want to use once there is no harm in using regex, but if it's something that you might want to reuse later regex might prove not the most reliable of tools.

**EDIT:**

fix for No. 5 - now the semicolon will be in the first matching group:

```
^(?:[^/]*)(;)(?!\S|(?:[^;]*\*/))
```

Comment: This assumes that a semicolon will never be followed by whitespace inside of a string. That's a very risky assumption.

Comment: For the sample input, it gave me 6 `;`s; I count 5.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I know, but on the other hand, why spend hours doing a regex that accounts for every possible case when usually good enough is enough. I tend to do the easiest possible thing first and update if someone gets back to me with more examples.