# regex to strip all comments from php code except between quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a project that should remove comments from php files. I find this code working:

```
(\/\*(?s:.*?)\*\/)|(\/\/.*)
```

but it also remove comments within php qoutes ( " and ' ). I do not want to remove comments in qoutes.

Comment: Finding matching quotation marks can be tricky (due to nested comments/strings, escape characters etc...). Regular Expressions might not be the right choice for that.

Comment: a good regex question should have a sample input, sample match, and sample output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that with only Regex.

However, this might help you: [Regex match semicolon but not in comments or quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562918/regex-match-semicolon-but-not-in-comments-or-quotes).

Answer (score 0):

http://rubular.com/r/rHXnGmdDUe

`(?:^|[^"]+[^"])\/\*\s+?.+?\*\/`

This is nowhere near exhaustive or fool-proof. You probably shouldn't be using regular expressions for this, and if you are, you should accept the possibility that it will probably catch a large number of false positives.

Comment: could you add single line comment support too?

Comment: have a minor problem, look at ; that highlighted.

Comment: Try `(?:^|[^;"]+[^"])(\/\*\s+?.+?\*\/)`